# cant sign apk in another machine (password incorrect or tampered with...)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having difficulties signing my apk for release. A friend of mine used to sign our applications but now I want to sign them aswell, he passed me by email the keystore file he uses to sign our applications but when I try to sign them (In eclipse Android tools -> Export Signed APK...) I choose his certificate and use the correct password.

Following these steps I am unable to sign the apk it always say the same:

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I've tried signing it using jarsigner, but no luck so far.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I've tried as well this

```
keytool -list -v -keystore path_to_keystore/keystore_name
```

And when I type the password i get the same error message

EDIT 2:

I've created another keystore using eclipse wizard and I've sent him by email and he can' use it aswell so I think we are missing a configuration step or something :\

EDIT 3:

I think we have made some progress, my friend changed the keystore password a a simpler one (the first one had the character '#' in it). And now I am able to run `keytool` command in cmd. But now I find the same problem again when I choose the alias password to sign the apk (it contains the character `#` aswell, is there any way to change alias password?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may sound stupid, but maybe you are using different keyboard layouts?

Comment: We have the same computer model and we both have the computers configured in spanish (ES-es).

Comment: There are 2 passwords -storepass and -keypass. Check those with your friend. Also keystore may include more than one aliases. Be sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: I've used in keytool -storepass and -keypass using the new password and it seems to work ok, the problem now is that we do not know why the alias password is not working either getting "ERROR: Cannot recovery key" message. And I am sure that I am typing the correct password, could it be a codification problem for using '#' character? or maybe the length of the password? It's weird

Comment: To change alias pass, have you seen this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-change-alias-passwords-of-your-android-keystore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments, changing the keystore password and the alias password solved the problem, not sure in the end if all of this was because the `#` character :\

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and not sure how to solve it.
When I try to sign using the correct password I get the next message: "keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect"

I used the

```
keytool -list -v -keystore path_to_keystore/keystore_name
```

and after typing the correct password I receive all key file content.  So I assume I have the correct password

Also I have tried to replace the password using the command

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore
```

After replacing the password, I tried to sign my apk with new password but neither work